# Child blocks and parent borders(Grid-Layout)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Why do child blocks **(block)** go beyond the boundaries of the parent block **(child_block)?**
I would like child blocks to automatically wrap to a new line

**How to achieve the result as in the screenshot:**
[image]

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');
            
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
let xep = document.createElement('div'); 
child_block.prepend(xep);
xep.className = 'block';
xep.innerHTML = 'Xopa'
}
```

```css
.main_block{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 100%; 
padding:10px;
margin:50px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.child_block{
display:grid;
grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.block{
display: inline-block;  
border:1px solid black;
font-size:18px;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">

<div class = "child_block">


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should look into CSS Flexbox instead of CSS Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this with `flex` too

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');
            
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
let xep = document.createElement('div'); 
child_block.prepend(xep);
xep.className = 'block';
xep.innerHTML = 'Xopa'
}
```

```css
.main_block{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 100%; 
padding:10px;
margin:50px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.child_block{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block{
display: inline-block;  
border:1px solid black;
font-size:18px;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">

<div class = "child_block">


</div>

</div>
```

and with `grid`

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');
            
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
let xep = document.createElement('div'); 
child_block.prepend(xep);
xep.className = 'block';
xep.innerHTML = 'Xopa'
}
```

```css
.main_block{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 100%; 
padding:10px;
margin:50px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.child_block{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(50px,1fr));
}

.block{
display: inline-block;  
border:1px solid black;
font-size:18px;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">

<div class = "child_block">


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you, is there a similar way on grid?

Comment: @alderman i update my answer

Comment: but here the width is fixed, if the text is even larger, it will go beyond the block border.
I did not think that the grid is so limited in functionality.
uh, now I have to learn how to use flex. thanks you again =)

Answer (score 1):

With the `inline-block` you've added to your Block elements, you don't even need to use any Grid Layout.

```js
let main = document.querySelector('.main_block');
let child_block = document.querySelector('.child_block');
            
for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
let xep = document.createElement('div'); 
child_block.prepend(xep);
xep.className = 'block';
xep.innerHTML = 'Xopa'
}
```

```css
.main_block{
padding:10px;
margin:50px;
border:1px solid black;
}

.block{
display: inline-block;
border:1px solid black;
font-size:18px;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "main_block">

<div class = "child_block">


</div>

</div>
```